# Very high traffic to DC port 389

Tags: domain-controller

We have been monitoring **very high** traffic between workstations on the branch offices with the HQ Domain Controllers port 389 (LDAP), where the workstations seem to be downloading some information from the DCs, in excess of 1 MB, and sometimes in excess of 20 (twenty!) MB. Not all workstations do this, though, but many of them.

What could possibly be the culprit here?

FYI, each branch office has an RODC already. All of them are 2008 R2.

Comment: Have you set up your AD locations correctly?

Comment: have you inspected event log in order to pin point some kind of anomaly?

Comment: Are the RODC's global catalogs too?  I can't imagine universal group caching being that large though.  Are there GPOs being assigned that pull data from shares on the HQ DC's?  I ask because of this link:http://www.hass.de/content/applying-software-gpo-takes-20-minutes-and-times-out-rodc-site

Comment: If it was GC traffic it would be on port 3268

Comment: @vautee yes, all sites and subnets have been properly created.

Comment: @ValerioMinetti nothing that immediately jumps out at me... just the usual warnings of "directory partition backup", "LDAP security can be significantly enhanced", and various Information-al events

Answer (score 0):

Check if the machines have a fax or mail application that pulls an address book from LDAP.

Comment: Hmm... that's interesting... not to the best of my knowledge, but I'll do a check this evening.